# Why my ajax/fetch call does not work with no Route in my controller?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I spent already long hours on the issue and I can not understand why my jquery ajax post does not work with `SurveyController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddComment(Survey survey)
        {
            if (survey == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            if (survey != null)
            {
                survey.Time = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Surveys.Add(survey);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Ajax:

```
const queryParams = `Name=${this.state.surveyState.name}&Change=${this.state.surveyState.change}&Opinion=${this.state.surveyState.opinion}`;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "/Survey/AddComment",
                        data: queryParams,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "html"
                    });
```

Routung from `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "Error", template: "Error",
                defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" });
                routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyProjects", action = "Index" });
            });
```

It gives me no errors in the console, but does not hit any breakpoints in the controller.

It works only when I use `[Route("comments/new")]` in my controller and `url: "/comments/new/AddComment",` in my Ajax.

I need to use `[HttpPost]` for the controller to be able to use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, I think so. But anyway, my Ajax and Controller are according to most of the popular examples for Ajax post that I could find here, and I have no idea why it doeas not work.

**EDIT:**

I tryed achieve the same with Fetch call:

```
const queryParams = `Name=${this.state.surveyState.name}&Change=${this.state.surveyState.change}&Opinion=${this.state.surveyState.opinion}`;
                    fetch(`/comments/new?`,
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: JSON.stringify({ queryParams }), // data can be `string` or {object}!
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                            credentials: 'include'
                        }
                    )
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(res => {
                            console.log(res);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error(error);
                        });
```

With the same result.
What I noticed, in `XHR` in console logs, call type is `GET` not `POST`, same for `AJAX` call. Why?

**UPDATE:**

Because of some reason, when change
`fetch(/comments/new?`
to
 `fetch(/Survey/AddComment`

XHR gives me still the same call URL:
`http://localhost:58256/comments/new?Name=aaa&Change=aaa&Opinion=good`

Whatever I wite over there, it does not change!!!(?).

**UPDATE:**

After removing `[Route("comments/new")]` and leaving `fetch("/Survey/AddComment"` there is no call at all.

**UPDATE**

After clearing whole browser's data, and using:
controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddComment([FromBody]Survey survey)
        {
            if (survey == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            survey.Time = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Surveys.Add(survey);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
```

Fetch:

```
const data = { 
                        Name: this.state.surveyState.name,
                        Change: this.state.surveyState.change,
                        Opinion: this.state.surveyState.opinion
                    };
                    fetch("/Survey/AddComment",
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                            body: JSON.stringify({ data}), // data can be `string` or {object}!
                            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                            credentials: 'include'
                        }
                    )
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(res => {
                            console.log(res);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error(error);
                        });
```

I am still getting XHR log for call URL:
`http://localhost:58256/comments/new?Name=aa&Change=aaa&Opinion=good`
Why?

Comment: It would help if you add the class Attributes, the class name of the controller (SurveyController???], the Attributes of the action AddComment() and perhaps the routing definition of your Startup.cs to the example. Of course if you want to handle a POST you have to use the Attribute HttpPost.

Comment: @koalabruder updated

Comment: I tryed it again with fetch call, with same result (please see edited question). What I noticed, in `XHR` console logs call type is `GET`, not `POST`, also for `ajax` call. I do not understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client side says it is sending `application/json`, But

```
const queryParams = `Name=${this.state.surveyState.name}&Change=${this.state.surveyState.change}&Opinion=${this.state.surveyState.opinion}`;
```

Is not JSON. Looks more like data you would send in a query string.

Construct a valid JSON payload

```
const data = { 
    Name: ${this.state.surveyState.name},
    Change: ${this.state.surveyState.change},
    Opinion: ${this.state.surveyState.opinion}
};
```

And send it in the correct format to the server

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Survey/AddComment",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Finally, let the Server action know to expect the data in the body of the request by using `[FromBody]`

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddComment([FromBody]Survey survey) {
    if (survey == null) {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    survey.Time = DateTime.Now;
    _context.Surveys.Add(survey);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I did like you posted, and nothing hits the break points inside of `public IActionResult AddComment([FromBody]Survey survey)`

Comment: I tryed it again with fetch call, with same result (please see edited question). What I noticed, in `XHR` console logs call type is `GET`, not `POST`, also for `ajax` call. I do not understand why?

Comment: @Przemyslaw.Pszemek in your update you still appear to be sending the data incorrectly. Review my answer carefully and notice how I construct the data to be sent.

Comment: @I tryed your approach, please see latest **UPDATE** on the question. Because of some reason, I am getting in `XHR` logs old URL: `http://localhost:58256/comments/new?Name=aa&Change=aaa&Opinion=good`, even after changing Fetch URL to: `/Survey/AddComment`. I have the same result also with using format: `${this.state.surveyState.name}` for the properties.

Comment: P.S. Do you think, that does it matter, that Fetch is called by React app?

Comment: P.P.S. thank you for your effort. Finally I noticed, that I didnt build app, really stupid mistake, long time I didnt write in React, so I was not updating changes. And to use Anti Forgery Tokens it was quite complex thing to do. Had to configure `Startup.cs`, read cookies by `JS` function, and send `"X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken` token in `Fetch` header. Probably same is for `Ajax`. Anyway, you helped me to understand better `Ajax` calls.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
```

means that the path `/Survey/AddComment` will call the Action

> SurveyController.AddComment()

The id marked with "?" is optional ({id?}).

If you want to define the route in the Controller you can do something like the following.

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class SurveyController : Controller {

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddComment(Survey survey)
    {
        survey.Time = DateTime.Now;
        _context.Surveys.Add(survey);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Content("Added");
    }
}
```

In both cases you have to mark the Action with [HttpPost] if you send a POST request.

Comment: I did like you proposed, and it does not go throu the action, because of some reason